# Undefined Offset 3 in array of 4 elements

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have been playing with the Steam api and PHP the last couple days and all was well until I started receiving strange offset errors and duplicate values in my array. I tried breaking the code down into a version without api calls and html, but still receive the same unknown error.

I know that the key value is the same as the array element 1 (so I can use array_key_exists()). I like having all the elements in a single array for printing to html. The objective of the program is to make a fast accumulation of the data retrieved in json.

> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in .../test.php on line 54 
>   AKA This line -> games[$gameId][3] += 1

```
 $games=array();
 $i=10;
 while($i>0){
     $i--;
     $playtime = rand(1,1500);
     $twpt = rand(1,300);
     $gameId = rand(5,15);

     // clearly 4 elements in the array to use
     $newEntry = array($gameId, $playtime, $twpt, 1);

     if(array_key_exists($gameId, $games)){
         $games[$gameId] = array(
             //$games[$gameId][0] will not change
             $games[$gameId][1] += $newEntry[1],
             $games[$gameId][2] += $newEntry[2],
             $games[$gameId][3] += 1
         );
     } else {
         $games[$gameId] = $newEntry;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you are "updating" (re-setting) `$games[$gameId][3]`.

```
$games[$gameId] = array(
    //$games[$gameId][0] will not change
    $games[$gameId][1] += $newEntry[1],
    $games[$gameId][2] += $newEntry[2],
    $games[$gameId][3] += 1
);
```

You are creating a *new* array, and are only adding 3 elements to it.  You need to add `$games[$gameId][0]` to the new array, so that it will have 4 elements.

```
$games[$gameId] = array(
    $games[$gameId][0],
    $games[$gameId][1] += $newEntry[1],
    $games[$gameId][2] += $newEntry[2],
    $games[$gameId][3] += 1
);
```

Or, instead of making a new array every time, just simply do:

```
if(array_key_exists($gameId, $games)){
    $games[$gameId][1] += $newEntry[1];
    $games[$gameId][2] += $newEntry[2];
    $games[$gameId][3] += 1;
}
else {
     $games[$gameId] = $newEntry;
}
```